# Silverlight 4 Timepicker

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

this is my xaml code for timePicker

```
<toolkit:TimePicker Name="timePickerStart" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Format="HH:mm"/>
```

what I want to achieve is that my drop box shows only full hours:

10: 00
11: 00
12 :00

By default it shows period of half an hour (10:00, 10:30, 11:00), I can manage that by changing PopupMinutesInterval property (lets say to 5, so it 'll be 10:05, 10:10, 10:15) , but of course it's only in range from 0 to 59 and I'm still short to get only full hours
Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/3538) issue on Codeplex, it seems like you are not the first to face this problem. Browsing the most recent [TimePicker source code](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77450#779272) the issue still seems to remain.

At this stage, the only suggestion I have to get around this problem is that you download the [toolkit source code](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), correct the bug and build your personal copy of the toolkit.